# While loop's code blocks being ignored until last one in code, while the delays are taken into account

Tags: java, timer, while-loop

The code from my Class.
When it is run I want the background color to go to orange for 100ms, then red, then orange again, and then a dark blue.

```
long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1 < 100)
{
    Buildings.background.setColor( Color.orange );
}
while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1 < 200)
{
    Buildings.background.setColor( Color.red );
}
while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1 < 300)
{
    Buildings.background.setColor( Color.orange );
}
while( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1 < 400)
{
    Buildings.background.setColor
       ( Color.blue.darker().darker() );
}
```

After running the code, I get just the blue, but it takes 300ms to set it.

Comment: The UI is (it seems) single-threaded. That means when your program busy-waits nothing related to the UI will happen, your loops will block the main event-handling loop. You need to figure out a way to handle all this *asynchronously*.

Answer (score 0):

the code will execute after running the program right?
so your program is taking  300 or more than 300 ms to execute that is why you are getting just the blue color.